# How can I automatically delete the MP4 version of a file if an MKV version exists?

Tags: file-management, batch-file

My upstream host has changed the way they send video files and I now have dozens of folders that contain both an MP4 and an MKV version of the same file. I want to keep the higher quality MKV file and delete the MP4 version, but there are too many to do by hand, plus it's likely that this will keep recurring until I get it straightened out.

So, I'd like to run a script / batch file that basically recursively looks through all of the subdirectories within the directory in which I run it, says `if exist <filename>.mkv, delete <filename>.* unless <filename>.nfo`

The files are on a NAS powered by Unraid, so I can ssh in and use Linux directly on the box, or I can use either an Ubuntu or Windows machine to do it via the network share, so I'm pretty flexible in where/how this runs.

Thank you in advance for any assistance on this. I've been ripping my hair out, Googling to see if I can find the solution but coming up empty.

Comment: Are the mkv and mp4 supposed to be in the same folder, and do you want to delete **all** files with the same base file name (except .mkv and .nfo)?

Comment: Yes and yes. The two files, mkv and mp4, will always be inside the same folder. Think \\tv\tvshowname\seasonx\individualshowname -- they'll be inside "seasonx".

Comment: Oh, and the idea behind 'delete <filename>.* unless <filename>.nfo' is in case it's not an MP4 that's the dupe, but an AVI. That happens, albeit rarely. Otherwise, a 'delete <filename>.mp4' would work.

Comment: Now i get confused. What is the connection between an .avi and an .nfo file, and how is it important for what you want to do?

Comment: Do you mean, you do not want to delete any duplicates if an .nfo file exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following in a .cmd file (or .bat file), and execute it in the root/base directory from where you want to start scanning and deleting for the duplicate video files.

The script will delete any files which have the same file name as a .mkv file in the same directory. But, it will not delete any .nfo files.

Additionally, the script is applying the same procedure to all sub-directories recursively.

Note the usage of `setlocal`. The script makes use of delayed environment variable expansion. However, this has the problem of swallowing up exlamation marks which might be part of a variable's content. To prevent this unwanted elimination of exclamation marks, delayed environment variable expansion is only enabled where necessary.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

echo Processing directory: "%CD%"

rem The outer for-loop goes through all ".mkv" files in the current folder.
rem The inner for-loop goes through all files with the same base file name
rem as the ".mkv" file and deletes them if its file extension is
rem neither ".mkv" nor ".nfo".

for %%i in (*.mkv) do (
    set BaseFileName=%%~ni

    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    for %%j in ("!BaseFileName!.*") do (
        set FileExtension=%%~xj
        if /i {!FileExtension!} neq {.mkv} if /i {!FileExtension!} neq {.nfo} (

            setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

            echo Deleting %%j
            del /q /f "%%j"

            endlocal
        )
    )

    endlocal
)

rem This for-loop is responsible for the recursion into sub directories.

set BatchFileAbsolutePath=%~df0
for /d %%i in (*.*) do (
    pushd "%%i"
    call "%BatchFileAbsolutePath%"
    popd
)
```

Comment: I dropped it into a sub folder to test, calling it test.bat, and got this error message:  <br/>

Z:\TestFolder>test.bat
Processing directory: Z:\TestFolder
'test' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.  <br/>

I'm on Windows7SP1, 64-bit, and I mapped a network drive (Z:) to the share (\\tv) to run the test. Am I missing a prerequisite?

Comment: ...What is the error message? Also, what Windows version do you use, and what is the absolute path of the "sub folder" you dropped it into?

Comment: Sorry, not used to this editor. Tried to edit to say this:


    I dropped it into a sub folder to test, calling it test.bat, and got this error message:

    Z:\TestFolder>test.bat Processing directory: Z:\TestFolder 'test' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

    I'm on Windows7SP1, 64-bit, and I mapped a network drive (Z:) to the share (\\tv) to run the test. Am I missing a prerequisite?

Comment: Argh, WTH can't I get the formatting to work? Sorry about that.

Comment: No, it's okay, i got the gist of it. Strange, it works here. Let me check, how it behaves when started from a root dir (like in your case).

Comment: Argh... stupid me. When i was testing, i had the script on a different drive, so i called it with its absolute path. I will fix my answer, it will just take a minute...

Comment: Okay, answer fixed. Note the modification at/around the for-loop for the sub-directory recursion.

Comment: That was absolutely amazing! It worked exactly as advertised and man, did it clean out a lot! Thank you *so* much!!!!!

Comment: Oops, one follow up - some of the folders use "&" in the name, resulting in errors like:   'Down' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.   In that example, the folder name is "Eastbound & Down". Is that fixable? If not, it's not a huge deal as the minor manual cleanup on those folders is much less than having to do the whole thing!

Comment: It's looping through the same folders over and over, btw. Once I realized that, I just did a Control-C to kill it.

Comment: Do you have by any chance a circular directory link/junction in your directory tree?

Comment: I think i know what happens. Because of the delayed expansion, the script might choke on exclamation marks in folder names. Let me check...

Comment: Check my updated answer please. By any chance, did you have in the same folder different files where the file name was exactly the same except for an exclamation mark (such as "Moon.mkv" and "Moon!.mkv")?

Comment: Following up - the updated answer works great. Even found some files the prior version had missed. Works exactly as advertised. As for your question -no, no names exactly the same except for an exclamation point. Thanks again!